# SWRevealViewController with StoryBoard with storyboard Identifier in Swift not segue how to do that

Tags: ios

SWRevealViewController how to implements the storyboard with storyboard identifier  in swift not segue  please help me

Answer (score 0):

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"StoryboardNibName" bundle:nil];
TempViewController *myVC = (TempViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"identifier"];
UIViewController *frontViewController = myVC;
RearViewController *rearViewController = [[RearViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *frontNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:frontViewController];
UINavigationController *rearNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rearViewController];
SWRevealViewController *revealController = [[SWRevealViewController alloc] initWithRearViewController:rearNavigationController frontViewController:frontNavigationController];
revealController.delegate = self;
self.viewController = revealController;
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Swift:

```
 let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
 let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TARGET_VIEW_CONTROLLER") as! UIViewController
 var rvc:SWRevealViewController = self.revealViewController() as SWRevealViewController
 rvc.pushFrontViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Comment: Thanks Nishant Gupta  Please can you do it in swift

Comment: same code  i am past in my AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions inside the method but it show error "Value of Type ‘AppDelegate’ has no member ‘revealViewController’"   this error got  for dis line     var rvc:SWRevealViewController = self.revealViewController() as SWRevealViewController